# Writing Query retrieving first value without top,fetch,limit

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a project, I have to write a query in SQL (on PostgreSQL), which retrieves the first artist whose death is after an artist, named "Louis Armstrong".
In the query, I cannot use FETCH, TOP, ROWNUM, LIMIT.

These are my tables

```
   ARTIST
   ID(PK)
   GID(PK)
   NAME(PK)
   SORT_NAME(PK)
   BEGIN_DATE_YEAR
   BEGIN_DATE_MONTH
   BEGIN_DATE_DAY
   TYPE(FK) --(TYPE NUMBER)

   ARTIST_TYPE
   ID(PK)
   NAME(PK)--(PERSON,GROUP,OTHER)
```

This is the query that I wrote down, is correct, but I cannot use the LIMIT clause

```
   SELECT A.NAME, 
   CONCAT_WS('/',A.BEGIN_DATE_DAY::text,A.BEGIN_DATE_MONTH::text,
   A.BEGIN_DATE_YEAR::text) AS DATA_NASCITA,
   CONCAT_WS('/',A.END_DATE_DAY::text,A.END_DATE_MONTH::text,
   A.END_DATE_YEAR::text) AS DATA_MORTE
   FROM artist AS A
   JOIN artist_type AS AT ON A.TYPE = AT.ID
   WHERE AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%' AND A.END_DATE_YEAR > ALL 
                (SELECT A.END_DATE_YEAR FROM artist AS A
                 JOIN artist_type AS AT ON A.TYPE = AT.ID
                 WHERE AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%' AND A.END_DATE_YEAR <= ALL
                     (
                         SELECT A.END_DATE_YEAR FROM artist AS A
                         JOIN artist_type AS AT ON A.TYPE = AT.ID
                         WHERE AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%' AND A.NAME LIKE 'Lou%'
                     )
                 )
           ORDER BY A.END_DATE_YEAR ASC
           LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ***WHY*** can't you use `FETCH, TOP, ROWNUM, LIMIT.`???

Comment: What means you "cannot use the LIMIT clause"? Do you get an error? Then please show the error message.

Comment: `ID(PK)
   GID(PK)
   NAME(PK) SORT_NAME(PK) ` You have  **four** primary keys? Or is it a composite key?

Comment: @wildplasser : As you can't have four primary keys, by definition, it only makes sense that these are the four columns in the composite primary key?

Comment: Your query does not match the description. Where does `AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%'` come from? And `A.END_DATE_YEAR`? Please present a consistent question, add proper table definitions (preferably `CREATE TABLE` scripts showing data types and constraints) and *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: @MatBailie because it's homework, the teacher, doesn't want to. It pisses me off, of course, but don't know what i can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you intended to write...

```
WITH
  artist_per AS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM artist        AS A
    JOIN artist_type   AS AT   ON AT.ID = A.TYPE
   WHERE AT.name LIKE 'Per%'
)
SELECT
  NAME,
  CONCAT_WS('/',BEGIN_DATE_DAY::text,BEGIN_DATE_MONTH::text,BEGIN_DATE_YEAR::text) AS DATA_NASCITA,
  CONCAT_WS('/',  END_DATE_DAY::text,  END_DATE_MONTH::text,  END_DATE_YEAR::text) AS DATA_MORTE
FROM
  artist_per
WHERE
  END_DATE = (
              SELECT MIN(END_DATE)
                FROM artist_per
               WHERE END_DATE > (
                                 SELECT MIN(END_DATE)
                                   FROM artist_per
                                  WHERE NAME LIKE 'Lou%'
                                )
             )
```

Will return one row, if only one person died on the date immediately after `Lou%` died.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. But what is the WITH clause, and why did you name the artist table with artist_per?

Comment: Because you do LIKE PER but don't explain why.

Comment: because I have to check if the artist type matches a person, so I used the wildcards...

Comment: So, then, the name I gave it means "artists that are persons"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make convoluted and slow code, you could try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT

  FIRST_VALUE(
    A.NAME
  ) OVER END_DATE_YEAR_ASC
                               AS NAME,
  FIRST_VALUE(
    CONCAT_WS('/',A.BEGIN_DATE_DAY::text,A.BEGIN_DATE_MONTH::text,A.BEGIN_DATE_YEAR::text)
  ) OVER END_DATE_YEAR_ASC
                               AS DATA_NASCITA,
  FIRST_VALUE(
    CONCAT_WS('/',A.END_DATE_DAY::text,A.END_DATE_MONTH::text,A.END_DATE_YEAR::text)
  ) OVER END_DATE_YEAR_ASC
                               AS DATA_MORTE
FROM
  <your query, without the ORDER BY>
WINDOW
  END_DATE_YEAR_ASC AS (ORDER BY A.END_DATE_YEAR)
```

Your `WHERE` clause, however, is "suspicious"...

First...

- `>  ALL(<some dates)` == `>  ( MAX(<some_dates>) )`
- `<= ALL(<some dates)` == `<= ( MIN(<some_dates>) )`

Unless you're expecting `NULL`s to be in there?

So, this gives...

```
WHERE
      AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%'
  AND A.END_DATE_YEAR
      >
      (
        # Latest [END_DATE_YEAR]
        #   Where that [END_DATE_YEAR] is before (or equal to)
        #     Earliest [END_DATE_YEAR] for 'Lou%'
        ############################################################
        SELECT MAX(A.END_DATE_YEAR)
          FROM artist AS A
          JOIN artist_type AS AT ON A.TYPE = AT.ID
         WHERE AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%'
           AND A.END_DATE_YEAR
               <=
               (
                 # Earliest [END_DATE_YEAR] for 'Lou%'
                 ############################################################
                 SELECT MIN(A.END_DATE_YEAR)
                   FROM artist AS A
                   JOIN artist_type AS AT ON A.TYPE = AT.ID
                  WHERE AT.NAME LIKE 'Per%'
                    AND A.NAME LIKE 'Lou%'
               )
      )
```

- Find the earliest death date of all `Lou%` artists.
- Find the latest death date that occurred before that.
- Find the earliest death that occurred after that.

Isn't that the death of the first `'Lou%'` to have died???

Comment: i have to know who died right after Louis.. That means that my result, includes just one row

Comment: @Seniker96 - My point is that your query appears to find Louis, not the person who died after Louis.

Comment: The query with the LIMIT 1 clause included, finds the person who died after Louis. Without the LIMIT 1, all the artist who died after Louis

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are forbidden to use `FETCH, TOP, ROWNUM, LIMIT`.
So it is just a matter of used logic, try reproducing this pseudo code:

```
select *
from artists a
where a.deathDate > (select deatheDate from artists where name = 'Louis Armstrong')
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from artists b
        where b.deathDate < a.deathDate
)
```

Warning! 
There can be more than one matching your criteria.